# Prove that if $a>b>0$, then $\frac{a-b}{a}<\ln a - \ln b <\frac{a-b}{b}$.

Tags: calculus, inequality

Prove that if $a>b>0$, then 
$$
\frac{a-b}{a}<\ln a - \ln b <\frac{a-b}{b}.
$$
This might/should be an application of the Mean Value Theorem

Comment: Just for the sake of culture: this is called Napier's inequality, as far as I remember.

Answer (score 5):

Divide $(a-b)$ this yields
$$\frac{1}{a} > \frac{\ln(a)-\ln(b)}{a-b}=\ln'(\xi)=\frac{1}{\xi} > \frac{1}{b}$$ 
with $\xi\in(b,a)$

And as $$a>b\implies \frac{1}{a}<\frac{1}{b}$$
your inequality is proved.

Comment: what does ln′(ξ) and 1/ξ here mean?

Comment: @user63764 See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem)

Comment: Ok I feel like I almost get it. Why does  a>b⟹1/a<1/b prove the inequality?

Comment: @user63 because $a > \xi > b \implies \frac{1}{a} < \frac{1}{\xi} < \frac{1}{b}$

Comment: I don't know why I'm asking this but, should it be $$1/a < (\ln a - \ln b)/(a - b) < 1/b$$ in there? Since in the question and the answers have the inequality reversed.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{a-b}{b}<\log a - \log b <\frac{a-b}{b}\iff\frac{1}{b}(a-b)<\log a-\log b<\frac{1}{a}(a-b)\iff$$

$$\frac{1}{b}(a-b)<\int\limits_b^a\frac{dx}{x}<\frac{1}{a}(a-b)$$

The above is just an application [Integral MVT](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=8&ved=0CFkQFjAH&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sju.edu%2F~pklingsb%2Fftc.pdf&ei=j5xRUe7YHpHY4QS9poGgBg&usg=AFQjCNFxD9bC2pqQnIC9xKUN2OuHXbnpdQ&sig2=wILkJsN8Sjr9V75VZiZ2Qw) (formula $(2)$) for the descending function $\,\frac{1}{x}\,$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** the derivative of $\ln x$ is $1/x$ and is decreasing on $(0,+\infty)$. Think about it after applying the mean value theorem.